# Google Map calculate formula of marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using *Google Maps* API to set location markers. Will placing e.g 10 marks using `setMap()` be "charged" by *Google* **ten** times or **one** time?

As far as I understand, `setMap()` just sets markers on an already "charged" API call. I just want some confirmation on this.

Comment: What does your code look like?  .

Answer (score 0):

If you are just placing markers by coordinates, the only quota that would apply would be for the API, which is counted by "API loads" from google's server (typically one per page view)